# Area probability question with circles

Tags: probability, area

The square target shown has sides of length 2 metres. Inside the square are a grey circle of radius 1 metre, and a black circle of radius 0.6 metres. Suppose that a dart thrown at the target
is equally likely to hit any part of the target.

[image: Circles in question with colours]

I have calculated the probabilities of hitting each region to be:

$Pr(W)=1-0.25\pi$

$Pr(G)=0.16\pi$

$Pr(B)=\frac{0.36\pi}{4}$

How would I approach the following question:

*Suppose that 10 points are awarded if the dart hits the grey region, five points if the dart hits the black region and zero points if the dart hits the white region. If two darts are thrown, the probability that the total score is 10 points is?*

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, list how you can get $10$ points in two throws of a dart.

a) Either you hit black region twice in a row and the probability is

$P(B) \cdot P(B)$

b) You hit grey region in one of the throws and white region in the other throw and the probability is

$P(G) \cdot P(W) + P(W) \cdot P(G)$

Finally add probability $(a)$ and $(b)$, which should give you the desired probability.